# Buffer for downloading files with express.js

Tags: node.js, express, buffer

Hello the javascript code below allows me to recover the files from the file system and send them to the frontend, however, when I run the code I have the following error what is it due to?

**Error:** TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type object, on this code

**JavaScript Code:**

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log("Recupero immagini");
    var request = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var action = request.pathname;
    //Recupero il logo della società
    if (action == '/logo.jpg') {
        console.log("Recupero logo");
        var img = fs.readFileSync('./Controller/logo.jpg');
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
        });
        res.end(img, 'binary');
    }
    //Recupero la firma del tecnico
    else if (action == '/firmatecnico.png') {
        console.log("Recupero logo tecnico");
        var img2 = fs.readFileSync('./firmatecnico.png');
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png'
        });
        res.end(img2, 'binary');
    }
}).listen(8570);
```

Comment: On which line is the error thrown?

Comment: @eol on res.end line and fs.readFileSync

Comment: Although this is not ideal (you're reading the whole file into memory and should be using streams/pipe) your code works fine on my machine. Can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure what the cause for the error is, you can try creating a read-stream from the files an pipe them into the response object (this is favorable as it does not read the whole file into memory):

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  // ...
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./path/to/your/file');
  fileStream.pipe(res);
  // ...

}).listen(8570);
```

Comment: but it's base64 return?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean? :)